# Asp.net Web Application Hosted on Server And Communication with Serial Port of Client Machine

Tags: asp.net

Weight machine is attached with the serial port of client's PC and client running web app. Now client wants to get the weight that weight machine sends on serial port in web app. I have web application deployed on IIS server, and i want to communicate with the serial port of client's PC. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably can't do that without the use of Java, ActiveX or similar, which I would not do. In the end, you'd have to create a client-side helper application that sends the serial data directly to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sir,Now I Have a window application which reads the weighing scale data .and now i want to store that output some where in memory and Put that data on web application textbox when some key is press..any idea??As far now i am using Clipboard to store that data but i  think i should do it in some other way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Got my Solution by Having A Window Application that interacts with serial port and from where i have generated a httpwebrequest as:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mydemo.co.in/WeightTest.aspx");
 request.Method = "Post";

            string formContent = "FormValue1=" + s + "&UserID=1";


            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formContent);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            //string responseFromServer = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());
            //You may need HttpUtility.HtmlDecode depending on the response

            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

And in my web application i have used a HttpCaching to store that weight As:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Params["FormValue1"]!= null)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Cache["Weight"] = Request.Params["FormValue1"];
        }
    }
```

Finally a have made a Web Request in my application through JQUERY to Put that weight in textbox of web application as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(GetWeight, 500);
    });
    function GetWeight()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            url: "WeightTest.aspx/GetWeight",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var info = data.d;
                if (info != null)
                    $("#txtWeight").val(info);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And all done.I am getting weight in real time on web application.
But one problem!! Since Caching is done globally then different users of my web application are getting that weight on that page.
One thing i need to do that somehow i want to send the client machine id From Client Side application and some how get that id in web application
and match those ids,
If ID Are same then provide the weight...!!!!!

Any Idea????